# Error: adding forEach in object prototype makes it readonly

Tags: javascript, object, foreach, prototype

I'd like to extend the object prototype, adding the `forEach` method.

I followed this guide [here](https://vanillajstoolkit.com/polyfills/objectforeach/), but this causes other stuff creating prototypes forEach to fail.
In my example I got the error with **RxJS**.

Is there a way to add the prototype `Object.forEach` but keeping it writeable for others?

```
if (!Object.prototype.forEach) {
    Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'forEach', {
        value: function (callback, thisArg) {
            if (this == null) {
                throw new TypeError('Not an object');
            }
            thisArg = thisArg || window;
            for (var key in this) {
                if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    callback.call(thisArg, this[key], key, this);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[Blitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-gvfuss)

Comment: Your code should be posted **here**, not on another site. Stack Overflow has facilities for create code tests and demonstrations as part of your question, just click the "<>" button.

Comment: "*I'd like to extend the object prototype,*" - well [please don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1048572).

Comment: Using `if (!Object.prototype.forEach) {` is bound to fail. Don't test this if you want to use *your* method.

Comment: @Bergi it's not my code, I'll improve it later.
Anyway I'm sick of having to use lodash or other stuff to do the object forEach. 
That's why I want the prototype...maybe thanks to your link I found something...

Comment: Use `for (const key in obj)` or `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj))` - no need for lodash `foreach` or extending `Object.prototype`. Or if you need an iterable key-value collection, use a `Map`.

Comment: *other stuff creating prototypes forEach to fail* — what "other stuff"? What is the other stuff trying to do? How does the other stuff fail exactly? What errors do you get? The `.definePrototype()` method creates a non-writable property by default, as you can see from the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Comment: @Bergi I've been using js for 20 years. I know the possible workarounds.

Comment: @Pointy it's written in the question...rxjs has a prototype forEach which can't be created because mine is readonly. Anyway as I said before I found out about the "writable".
Thanks both for your time!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `writable: true` does the trick

see: [define property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#description)

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'forEach', {
    writable: true,
    value: function (callback: ObjectForEachCallback, thisArg: any) {
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('Not an object');
      }
      thisArg = thisArg || window;
      for (const key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          const res = callback.call(thisArg, this[key], key);
          if (res === false) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    },
  });
```